# How to set the stroke of the embedded image in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I just need to highlight embedded images on a white background, so I tried to set the stroke of the embedded images, but the ***Fill And Stroke*** option does nothing. How can I achieve this for a group of many images when drawing a rectangle manually around each of them takes too much time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the embedded image is a raster image then you can't.  Fill and stroke attributes can only be applied to vector objects.

A possible workaround is to apply an outline filter to the raster images.

1. Select all the raster images (holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click each image will allow you to make a multiple selection)
2. Do *Filters > Morphology > Outline* - adjust the sliders, choose a colour etc. Note: if changing the colour, you may need to deselect the preview and re-enable it for the preview to refresh.

Example

[image]

Note also that the filter can be copied just like other style attributes. So, if you've applied it to one image, you can do *Edit > Copy*, then select another image and do *Edit > Paste Style* to apply the same filter.

Answer (score 2):

Two more options:

---

1. Pattern:

   - Select the image,
   - do Object > Pattern > Convert to pattern,
   - and apply the stroke afterwards.

The object will now be filled with a repeating pattern, but as long as you don't change the object's size or move the pattern handles, you won't see that.

---

2. Additional Rectangle:

   - Select the image,
   - copy it to the clipboard.
   - Draw an arbitrary rectangle (without a stroke).
   - Edit > Paste Size > Paste Size (of the image to the rectangle).
   - Set a stroke on the rectangle,
   - and make it twice as wide as the border you need.
   - Select both rectangle and image.
   - Align them with Ctrl+Alt+keypad 5.

Comment: The use of a pattern is a really nice idea. I'd never have thought of that! +1